# iOS - sqlite3_column_origin_name

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite

Did anyone tried this function (sqlite3_column_origin_name) on Objective-C? It exists in sqlite3.h but I get an error when I try to use it:

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_sqlite3_column_origin_name", referenced from:
      +[SQLCommunication executeSelect:] in SQLCommunication.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I use sqlite3_column_name(). I also find sqlite3_column_origin_name() does not work in IOS.

Answer (score 0):

For resolve your question [see this link](http://www.spatialvision.com.au/index.php/component/content/article/58-tech-tips/601-adding-a-custom-sqlite-build-to-an-xcode-project.html) and changing the definition `#define SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS4` to this `#define SQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA`